# How to get rid of "The web.xml file does not exist" error in Eclipse from GWT Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I use Eclipse to develop my `REST` server, and `GWT` client in one project. To build this project I use `Maven`. Server side code is developed in `Spring Framework` and everything I configure using `Java` instead of `XML` files, so I don't have any `web.xml` file.

To compile project I have in maven `pom.xml` special entry as follow:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Application (Spring server side and GWT client side) compiles and works as supposed. There is no problem, beside Eclipse, which point me out that I don't have `web.xml` file. Here is whole Eclipse error information:

```
Description                     | Resource | Path                 | Location | Type

The web.xml file does not exist | WEB-INF  | /cms/src/main/webapp | Unknown  | Google Web App Problem
```

[image]

As You can see error comes from GWT Eclipse plugin. But this plugin doesn't know that I use GWT only for client, and it shouldn't report me that error.

I wonder can and how to turn it off.

Comment: What is the error information that you are referring to, since you say that the compilation is successful?

Comment: I think That I've put that in the post? Can You be more specific? I've added screen from eclipse, where is an error.

Comment: Do you use GWT RPC by any chance?

Comment: No. GWT is only for client. I use Resty-GWT to send requests to server. But On server side there is no GWT at all.

Comment: What version of GWT are you using?  Are you referring to any <welcome-file> in web.xml accidentally from your GWT <entry-point> class?

Comment: GWT 2.7. I don't think so, I don't have entry point. I use GWTP and gin.

Comment: There should be a way to silence it; either from the GWT plugin for Eclipse, or Eclipse itself. Have you tried right clicking the error? Or search in the settings?

Comment: All I could do is to click RMB on this error entry and `Delete` it.

Comment: But the error comes back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To turn this check off:
(in Eclipse)
Window -> Preferences -> Google -> Errors/Warnings -> Project structure and SDKs -> Missing web.xml

Comment: Thanks for great answer. It's bad that it is for whole eclipse. It should be project level configuration, not ide level configuration.